# How to randomly select a string from an array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I am very new to coding so please forgive me.

I have saved some example strings in an array:

```
Dim intArray(0 To 2) As String
    intArray(0) = "I will be on time for class"
    intArray(1) = "I will be prepared for class"
    intArray(2) = "I will listen to the teacher and follow instructions"

    lblTestSWPB.Text = intArray(0)
```

I know that it works when I click the button to generate for (0) - obviously.Is there a way to add something to make the label display a string at random from the array?

Comment: The way to get an element from the array is to provide the index of the element, which you already know how to do.  The way to get a random element is to generate a random number and use that as the index.  It is VERY easy to find out how to generate a random number in VB.NET.  Just search the web for the obvious keywords.  Just make sure to ignore any results that do not use the `Random` class.  Anything that uses `Randomize` and `Rnd` should be ignored as it's basically using VB6-style code.

Comment: Also the question title is a bit misleading. The question itself has nothing to do with *generating random strings*.

Answer (score 0):

You may use something like: `Random` class

```
Dim rnd As New Random 'Make sure that you declare it as New, 
'otherwise, it thorws an Exception(NullReferenceException)
Dim intArray(0 To 2) As String

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    intArray(0) = "I will be on time for class"
    intArray(1) = "I will be prepared for class"
    intArray(2) = "I will listen to the teacher and follow instructions"
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    lblTestSWPB.Text = intArray(rnd.Next(0, 3))
End Sub
```

Note that `rnd.Next` is a Function that returns a random Integer from the minimum is the inclusive lower bound and the maximum is the exclusive upper bound.(Thanks to @Enigmativity for the correction.) [Click this link if this answer is still unclear for you](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2dx6wyd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It would be worthwhile discussing that the maximum value in `rnd.Next` is an _exclusive_ maximum.